# Getting NVIDIA OpenCL to work on OpenCV 2.4.10

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, opencl

I am trying to get a sample OpenCL code from OpenCV directories to work. The sample code is "squares.cpp":

```
// The "Square Detector" program.
// It loads several images sequentially and tries to find squares in
// each image

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define ACCURACY_CHECK

#ifdef ACCURACY_CHECK
// check if two vectors of vector of points are near or not
// prior assumption is that they are in correct order
static bool checkPoints(
    vector< vector<Point> > set1,
    vector< vector<Point> > set2,
    int maxDiff = 5)
{
    if(set1.size() != set2.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(vector< vector<Point> >::iterator it1 = set1.begin(), it2 = set2.begin();
            it1 < set1.end() && it2 < set2.end(); it1 ++, it2 ++)
    {
        vector<Point> pts1 = *it1;
        vector<Point> pts2 = *it2;


        if(pts1.size() != pts2.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
        for(size_t i = 0; i < pts1.size(); i ++)
        {
            Point pt1 = pts1[i], pt2 = pts2[i];
            if(std::abs(pt1.x - pt2.x) > maxDiff ||
                    std::abs(pt1.y - pt2.y) > maxDiff)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
#endif

int thresh = 50, N = 11;
const char* wndname = "OpenCL Square Detection Demo";


// helper function:
// finds a cosine of angle between vectors
// from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2
static double angle( Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}


// returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
// the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
static void findSquares( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    squares.clear();
    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
    pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        // try several threshold levels
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                cv::threshold(gray0, gray, (l+1)*255/N, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            vector<Point> approx;

            // test each contour
            for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if( approx.size() == 4 &&
                        fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                        isContourConvex(Mat(approx)) )
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                    {
                        // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence
                    if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
// the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
static void findSquares_ocl( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    squares.clear();

    Mat gray;
    cv::ocl::oclMat pyr_ocl, timg_ocl, gray0_ocl, gray_ocl;

    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    ocl::pyrDown(ocl::oclMat(image), pyr_ocl);
    ocl::pyrUp(pyr_ocl, timg_ocl);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<cv::ocl::oclMat> gray0s;
    ocl::split(timg_ocl, gray0s); // split 3 channels into a vector of oclMat
    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        gray0_ocl = gray0s[c];
        // try several threshold levels
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                // do canny on OpenCL device
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                cv::ocl::Canny(gray0_ocl, gray_ocl, 0, thresh, 5);
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments
                ocl::dilate(gray_ocl, gray_ocl, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
                gray = Mat(gray_ocl);
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                cv::ocl::threshold(gray0_ocl, gray_ocl, (l+1)*255/N, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
                gray = gray_ocl;
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            vector<Point> approx;
            // test each contour
            for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if( approx.size() == 4 &&
                        fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                        isContourConvex(Mat(approx)) )
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;
                    for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                    {
                        // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence
                    if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// the function draws all the squares in the image
static void drawSquares( Mat& image, const vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
    {
        const Point* p = &squares[i][0];
        int n = (int)squares[i].size();
        polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA);
    }
}


// draw both pure-C++ and ocl square results onto a single image
static Mat drawSquaresBoth( const Mat& image,
                            const vector<vector<Point> >& sqsCPP,
                            const vector<vector<Point> >& sqsOCL
)
{
    Mat imgToShow(Size(image.cols * 2, image.rows), image.type());
    Mat lImg = imgToShow(Rect(Point(0, 0), image.size()));
    Mat rImg = imgToShow(Rect(Point(image.cols, 0), image.size()));
    image.copyTo(lImg);
    image.copyTo(rImg);
    drawSquares(lImg, sqsCPP);
    drawSquares(rImg, sqsOCL);
    float fontScale = 0.8f;
    Scalar white = Scalar::all(255), black = Scalar::all(0);

    putText(lImg, "C++", Point(10, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, fontScale, black, 2);
    putText(rImg, "OCL", Point(10, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, fontScale, black, 2);
    putText(lImg, "C++", Point(10, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, fontScale, white, 1);
    putText(rImg, "OCL", Point(10, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, fontScale, white, 1);

    return imgToShow;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* keys =
        "{ i | input   |                    | specify input image }"
        "{ o | output  | squares_output.jpg | specify output save path}"
        "{ h | help    | false              | print help message }";
    CommandLineParser cmd(argc, argv, keys);
    string inputName = cmd.get<string>("i");
    string outfile = cmd.get<string>("o");

    if(cmd.get<bool>("help"))
    {
        cout << "Usage : squares [options]" << endl;
        cout << "Available options:" << endl;
        cmd.printParams();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    int iterations = 10;
    namedWindow( wndname, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    vector<vector<Point> > squares_cpu, squares_ocl;

    Mat image = imread(inputName, 1);
    if( image.empty() )
    {
        cout << "Couldn't load " << inputName << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int j = iterations;
    int64 t_ocl = 0, t_cpp = 0;
    //warm-ups
    cout << "warming up ..." << endl;
    findSquares(image, squares_cpu);
    findSquares_ocl(image, squares_ocl);


#ifdef ACCURACY_CHECK
    cout << "Checking ocl accuracy ... " << endl;
    cout << (checkPoints(squares_cpu, squares_ocl) ? "Pass" : "Failed") << endl;
#endif
    do
    {
        int64 t_start = cv::getTickCount();
        findSquares(image, squares_cpu);
        t_cpp += cv::getTickCount() - t_start;


        t_start  = cv::getTickCount();
        findSquares_ocl(image, squares_ocl);
        t_ocl += cv::getTickCount() - t_start;
        cout << "run loop: " << j << endl;
    }
    while(--j);
    cout << "cpp average time: " << 1000.0f * (double)t_cpp / getTickFrequency() / iterations << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "ocl average time: " << 1000.0f * (double)t_ocl / getTickFrequency() / iterations << "ms" << endl;

    Mat result = drawSquaresBoth(image, squares_cpu, squares_ocl);
    imshow(wndname, result);
    imwrite(outfile, result);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have installed the cuda framework; but I get the following error when I try to run the code in visual studio 2013:

```
warming up ...
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (CL_INVALID_VALUE) in cv::ocl::ContextImpl::ContextIm
pl, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\ocl\src\cl_con
text.cpp, line 578
ERROR: Can't select OpenCL device: GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST(NVIDIA CUDA)
ERROR: Required OpenCL device not found, check configuration:
    Platform: any
    Device types: GPU CPU
    Device name: any
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -221 (Can't select OpenCL device) in cv::ocl::C
ontextImpl::getContext, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\mo
dules\ocl\src\cl_context.cpp, line 684
```

**UPDATE:**
this is the output of CLinfo:

```
Number of platforms:    1
        CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE:    FULL_PROFILE
        CL_PLATFORM_VERSION:    OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 7.0.0
        CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR:     NVIDIA Corporation
        CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS: cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_
gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unro
ll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_shari
ng cl_nv_copy_opts
        Number of devices:      1
                CL_DEVICE_TYPE: CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
                CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID:    4318
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:    4
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS:     3
        CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:  1024 1024 64
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:  1024
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_CHAR:  1
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_SHORT: 1
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT:   1
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG:  1
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT: 1
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE:        1
                CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_HALF:  0
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_CHAR:     1
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_SHORT:    1
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT:      1
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG:     1
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT:    1
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE:   1
                CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_HALF:     0
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:  1097
                CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS: 64
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:   536870912
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:        1
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:  256
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS: 16
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_WIDTH:    16384
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_WIDTH:    16384
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_HEIGHT:   16384
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_WIDTH:    4096
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_HEIGHT:   4096
                CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_DEPTH:    4096
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_SAMPLERS: 32
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE:   4352
                CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN:  4096
                CL_DEVICE_MIN_DATA_TYPE_ALIGN_SIZE:     128
                CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG:     CL_FP_DENORM | CL_FP_INF_NAN | C
L_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST | CL_FP_ROUND_TO_ZERO | CL_FP_ROUND_TO_INF | CL_FP_FMA
                CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG:     CL_READ_ONLY_CACHE | CL_READ_WRI
TE_CACHE
                CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_TYPE:        CL_READ_WRITE_CACHE
                CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHELINE_SIZE:    128
                CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE:        65536
                CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:      2147483648
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE:     65536
                CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS:    9
                CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:
                CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       49151
                CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT:     0
                CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY:  0
                CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION:   1000
                CL_DEVICE_ENDIAN_LITTLE:        1
                CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE:    1
                CL_DEVICE_COMPILER_AVAILABLE:   1
                CL_DEVICE_EXECUTION_CAPABILITIES:       CL_EXEC_KERNEL
                CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_
ENABLE | CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
                CL_DEVICE_PLATFORM:     000000DA609B27F0
        CL_DEVICE_NAME: GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST
        CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:       NVIDIA Corporation
        CL_DRIVER_VERSION:      350.12
        CL_DEVICE_PROFILE:      FULL_PROFILE
        CL_DEVICE_VERSION:      OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
        CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION:     OpenCL C 1.2
        CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS:   cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_
gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unro
ll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_shari
ng cl_nv_copy_opts  cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extende
d_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl
_khr_fp64
```

what should be the setting for `OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE` ? I have tried `:GPU:NVIDIA`, `:GPU:GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST`, `:GPU:GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST<NVIDIA CUDA>` and the error persists !

**UPDATE2:**
with settings `:GPU:0` and `:GPU:1` I get the following errors respectively:

```
warming up ...
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (CL_INVALID_VALUE) in cv::ocl::ContextImpl::ContextIm
pl, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\ocl\src\cl_con
text.cpp, line 578
ERROR: Can't select OpenCL device: GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST(NVIDIA CUDA)
ERROR: Required OpenCL device not found, check configuration: :GPU:0
    Platform: any
    Device types: GPU
    Device name: 0
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -221 (Can't select OpenCL device) in cv::ocl::C
ontextImpl::getContext, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\mo
dules\ocl\src\cl_context.cpp, line 684
```

and with `:GPU:1`(which is a little different error, length-wise):

```
warming up ...
ERROR: Required OpenCL device not found, check configuration: :GPU:1
    Platform: any
    Device types: GPU
    Device name: 1
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -221 (Can't select OpenCL device) in cv::ocl::C
ontextImpl::getContext, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\mo
dules\ocl\src\cl_context.cpp, line 684
```

I also took a screenshot of the environment settings to double check that I set these values correctly:

[image]

Comment: Please note that CUDA has nothing to do with OpenCL. I suggest you get OpenCV 3 and use [this guide](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/10/15/opencv-3-0-transparent-api-opencl-acceleration/). Worked for me.

Comment: @antonio but i believe that it is the cuda framework and its gdk that allows opencl be compiled via its libraries on nvidia gpus. Because how else can you ! Furthermore since opencl functions have become a branch of the original functions, and they operate if they detect opencl libraries on your system, how can you be sure if you are using the intended opencl functions ?

Comment: Regarding your last question, the only reliable way is to install a GPU monitoring software, and see if the GPU is effectively working. CUDA and OpenCL are different, NVidia provides an OpenCL implementation (you get it when you install the NVidia drivers), but the sad truth is that they are not really putting a big effort into that, several OpenCL functions are not available yet for NVidia. They support OpenCL protocol 1.2, but not 2.0. ATI does support it.

Comment: @antonio that is supposed to change soon, very soon  but I'm not quite sure when.  It made some news a while ago and the OpenCL group chairman is still a guy at NVidia - its definitely going to get a revision this decade..

Comment: @AmirHosseinF no updates?  what is the current setting of OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE?  What is the output of clinfo?

Comment: @AmirHosseinF could you try setting OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE=:GPU:0 ?  If that fails, also try :GPU:1 - its not clear from their examples if they use 1-index or 0-index

Comment: @JasonNewton I have updated my post, following your suggestions, the error still persists

Comment: @AmirHosseinF can you run any OpenCL examples from NVidia?  It looks like :GPU:0 and being unset both find and try the correct device.

Comment: @JasonNewton The problem is resolved downgrading the NVIDIA driver to 344.75 version. but now the OpenCL version is 1.1. I believe it had a problem with OpenCL 1.2. I'll try OpenCV 3.0 now to see if it can use OpenCL1.2 ! But now the thing is that the code on openCL is slower than CPU !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is resolved downgrading the NVIDIA driver to 344.75**

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are failing to open the device because the name may not be found or is just failing to string match with the way the OpenCV OpenCL configuration parser works.  Try something simpler.

[Link to doc on setting OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html):

If this fails, double check that clinfo is picking up your device.